# mod_rewrite doesn't work in Chrome and Internet Explorer as in Firefox

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cross-browser

I have a domain like `example.test.com`. The website consists of three different html files:

- index.html
- products.html
- contact.html

So if a user types in `example.test.com/index.html` the url should be redirected to `example.test.com`.

Also `example.test.com/index` should become `example.test.com`

`example.test.com/contact.html` should be `example.test.com/contact` and so on.

Their should be no `www` before the url.

I came up with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html?|php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://example.test.com/ [R=301,L]
```

In Firefox everything works as expected, but in Chrome and Internet Explorer `example.test.com/index.html` is only redirected to `example.test.com/index` and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with the  `^[A-Z]{3,9}\` part but the culprit here is the dot at the end of index in your last condition. Change it to :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index(|\.html|\.php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://example.test.com/ [R=301,L]
```

and this should work fine.